# iOS Game Center - authentication error on one device

Tags: ios, authentication, game-center, nserror

On one of my devices (an iPad mini running iOS7), when I attempt to authenticate in Game Center I get the dreaded error:

```
Authentication Error: Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=2 "The requested operation has been cancelled or disabled by the user." UserInfo=0x15ef0f00 {NSLocalizedDescription=The requested operation has been cancelled or disabled by the user.}
```

I am clearly logged into Game Center. I have completely wiped the app from the device and even a fresh run from Xcode after deleting the app I still get the error.

I can log in with other devices with no problem. I'm signed into the same GC account on different devices. It's just that on this particular device it will not authenticate my app, nor does the app show up in the "Games" list in the Game Center app.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are using ios7 then reset your device and if you are using older ios then open gamecenter app and logout from there and do login again.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was having this same issue with an iPad 3 (retina) running iOS7 - evidently in iOS7 if Game Center is dismissed from your app 3 times the user is NEVER prompted again, and there is no way to reset this by re-logging in to Game Center (as you could in iOS6).

The current fix that worked for me is to reset settings - Settings->General->Reset->Reset All Settings.

Hopefully Apple fixes this bug in the next release, or at least provides better Game Center documentation for iOS7.

Comment: Yeah that worked for me too. Crazy that the user can't even log in if they want to. Nobody is going to know to Reset All Settings.

Comment: I just submitted a bug report to Apple. You guys should do the same if it bothers you.

Comment: FYI Apple got back to me and they fixed this problem as of iOS 7.1

Comment: Does not appear to be fixed in iOS 7.1.1, I can easily replicate on all builds of iOS 7. Is there something in code we need to do to work around this?

Comment: Problem persists in iOS 8.1.2

Comment: .. And in iOS 8.3 still

Answer (score 1):

+1 to workaround above (kristiankeane). Strangely this is only a pb for iOS7 devices. For iOS7 simulator, I was able to log out/log in from Game Center app to get out of a the 3 strikes behavior.
(I mean this as a comment to the answer above but I can't add comments yet)