# Save game data into iCloud via GameKit not working

Tags: ios, save, icloud, gamekit, icloud-drive

When I try to save or load game data, I get the following error:

**Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=27 "The requested operation could not be completed because you are not signed in to iCloud or have not enabled iCloud Drive"**

I'm testing on my iPad2 (iOS 9.2.1) with a developer provisioning profile that has iCloud enabled, and I am signed in to iCloud and have iCloud Drive enabled, so what could possibly cause that error?

Comment: Check this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148422/ios-game-center-authentication-error-on-one-device..good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work :(

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, did you ever resolve this problem?